# Different component in a same React route based on roles

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to set different component on a same React route based on user roles.

Here's what I did.

```
// AppRouter.js
const AppRouter = () => {

    const {loading, data, error}  = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER)

    if (loading) return <span>Loading...</span>
    if (error) return <Redirect to="/login"/>

    if (data) {
        let {me: {role}}= data

        if (role === 'user') {
            return (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route to="/" component={EmployeeHome}/>
                        <Route path="/login" exact component={SigninForm} />
                    </Switch>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                    <Switch>
                    <Route to="/" component={AdminHome}/>
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={SigninForm} />
                    </Switch>
            )
        }
    }

}

// App.js
    <Router history={history}>
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <h3>This is header!</h3>
        </header>
        <Switch>
          <AppRouter />
          <Route path="/login" component={SigninForm} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

1. Call a graphql query that retrieves the current user based on the authorization token stored in localStorage.
2. If error, will redirect to /login
3. If successful, will create a specific routes available for that particular role.
   3a. If role is user, it will create a route which has a EmployeeHome component
   3b. If role is admin, it will create a route which has a AdminHome component

After trying the the code above, it doesn't load the SigninForm which points to `/login` route.

What should be done to make this work?

Added: [Replicable Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-archimedes-9y964)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Switch` in `AppRouter` component unless it has "nested" routes. Also, no need to define `/login` route more than once.

```
<Router history={history}>
  // ... header here
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={SigninForm} />
    <AppRouter />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

where `AppRouter` is:

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  // define loading, error, role etc. 

  if (loading) return <span>Loading...</span>
  if (error) return <Redirect to="/login" />

  if (role === 'user') {
    return (
      <>
        <Route exact path="/" component={EmployeeHome} />
      </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Route exact path="/" component={AdminHome} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And, `<Redirect to="/login" />` should not be the very first line in your router setup as it will keep redirecting to "/login" without seeing further defined routes, hence won't render anything. Your current setup in `AppRouter` return `<Redirect to="/login" />` when there is an **error** and in that case, it becomes the very first line which is problematic.

Though, you can write something like this: `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />`.

Comment: I tried you code above, when accessing the "/login" path directly, the component rendered properly, but when I tried to access the path through `Redirect` does not render the component. I also tried `<Redirect exact from="/" to="/login"/>` but it doesn't render the component.

Comment: After updating the code, graphql authentication failure message (from the backend) was logged in the console. The browser url also changed to "/login".
I will try to make a codesandbox if this issue replicate even if there's no graphql server added.

Comment: I've added a replicable codesandbox in the post.

Comment: I think it was `history` version issue. So, better to remove it as the correct version will be automatically added by react-router-dom.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that there are issues with latest history version and react-router-dom version.

Comment: Yes, I just wrote another answer: [React router not working property on latest, v5, version of "history"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)