# react app showing empty page when redirecting on production build

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a reactJs app which is running on a server that has nginx on it.
The problem is that when I try to redirect from HomePage("/") to /UserPanel or /AdminPanel
the url changes but it shows an empty page, but then when i reload the page, it works just fine.
This problem doesn't occur in my localhost, but it happens to the production build.

this is my nginx config:

```
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

       
        root /var/app/html;

        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
        }
```

And this is my main app class:

```
import { Route, Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Snackbar />
        <Router history={hist}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Pace color={theme.palette.secondary.main} />
            <Suspense fallback={<Fragment />}>
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute
                  path="/AdminPanel"
                  component={AdminPanel}
                />
                <PrivateRoute
                  path="/UserPanel"
                  component={UserPanel}
                />
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              </Switch>
            </Suspense>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And I am redirecting from HomePage like this:

```
const redirect = () => {
    let url = isAdmin
      ? URLConstant.ADMIN_PANEL
      : isUser
      ? URLConstant.USER_PANEL
      : null;
    if (url) {
      return (
        <Redirect
          push
          to={{
            pathname: url,
            state: {}
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  };
```

And I'm using "react-router": "^5.2.0", "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0", "history": "latest".

What am I doing wrong? Should I add anything other than urls in .env?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AjeetShah I Edited the question to provide the information you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @AjeetShah yes I have imported history in package.json ("history": "latest").

Comment: @AjeetShah I am using Router from "react-router-dom".

Comment: I don’t know about Nginx confit but I think that’s the problem. You want all requests to go to index.HTML, so react code runs.

Comment: @AlanP. so I should use BrowserRouter instead?

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks. I will give it a try right now

Comment: @AjeetShah Thanks Man!! That solved it. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrade your "history" version or simply remove it because the correct version will be automatically added by "react-router-dom".

There is already an open issue about the same:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804

Which says React Router (mainly `history.push` and `Redirect`) is not working properly with latest (v5) version of **history**. But it is working perfectly with v4 of history.

For example, this should work:

```
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a `"homepage": ".",` inside your `package.json`.