# Using History.Push From a Thunk Action-Creator but No Methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-history

I am trying to redirect from the action creator rather than from the form componenets, because I feel it would be clearer.

So I export an `history` from `history.js`

```
//history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Then import `history` to be used in the action creator

```
//action.js
import { history } from './history';

export const register = (formData) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
            //...various dispatch sent
            history.push('/');
    }
}
```

but when I run `history.push()` I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function
```

And it seem that `history` itself is not what it should be:

```
history
History {length: 50, scrollRestoration: "auto", state: null}
```

How can use `history.push()` from outside a react componenet?

---

yarn.lock: history@^5.0.0

Comment: What version of history are you using?

Comment: this is in `yarn.lock`: history@^5.0.0:

Comment: What's your bundling process look like? Clearly `history.push()` is a function, and as you pointed out, the history Object doesn't even contain the correct properties. And I'm assuming none of the other `history` methods work either (i.e., history.go(), history.replace(), etc.)? The issue isn't that you're using it outside of a react component, it has nothing to do with react (that's `react-router`, which also relies on `history`).

Comment: ok, I removed React thanks. And yes, nothing works, doesn't seem that the right history is passed in... I have no clue of what goes wrong

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)