# Navigation using Link with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

TL;DR `react-router-dom` reaches default route on navigation, but works fine on refresh. I want to find & fix the issue.

I need to call logout from axios interceptor, so I use history API. It requires `router` instead of `browserrouter`. I have setup a sample code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cscupr?file=src%2FApp.js

Snippet:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch, useHistory, create } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={() => (
            <h1>
              HomePage
              <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
            </h1>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/test" exact component={Test} />
        <Route render={() => <h1>404: not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Test() {
  return <h1> Test Page</h1>;
}
```

Now if I click that test link in the above example it goes to 404 page. But if I refresh browser it loads the test page without any issue.

if I'm using click to navigate I see `location` has `action` & another property called `location`

[image: router props in debug view]

But if I just refresh the page, same props doesn't have `action` and `location` object seems to be valid

[image: router props on refresh debug view]

1. Does `router` support link based navigation? If not how to keep declarative links with history supported routing?
2. I see `browserrouter` doesn't support custom history. Is it possible to call redirect outside a functional component? I'm not using redux and looking for simple react based solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this issue after downgrading to history@4

> Documentation for version 4 can be found on the v4 branch. Version 4
> is used in React Router versions 4 and 5.

Working Fork with history@4.10.1: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sd7uze?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Related: [react app showing empty page when redirecting on production build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the imported `Router` to `BrowserRouter`. You can read [more](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/primary-components#:%7E:text=At%20the%20core%20of%20every,BrowserRouter%3E%20uses%20regular%20URL%20paths.) about the differences. Try:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, useHistory, create } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={() => (
            <h1>
              HomePage
              <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
            </h1>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/test" exact component={Test} />
        <Route render={() => <h1>404: not found</h1>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Test() {
  return <h1> Test Page</h1>;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I need to use router because browserRouter doesn't support history