# Changing url without displaying the page

Tags: reactjs, routes, history

There is a problem navigating to the application page. When clicked, the url changes, but the content does not change. Wrapped connect in withRouter but doesn't help. I'm using webpack 5, but I haven't configured anything for routing. Where could the problem be with this implementation?

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import history from "./utils/history";
import './App.css';
import AuthLayout from "./containers/auth-controller";
import Menu from './components/menu';
import {
    Router,
    Switch,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import routes from './routes'

function App() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
                <AuthLayout>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Menu/>
                        <div className="page">
                            {routes}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </AuthLayout>
            </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import history from "./utils/history";

let React = require('react');
let ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import './index.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <App/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Route.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Component from './component';

export default <Route exact path="/tests" component={Component} />;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as Pages from './pages';

export default (
    <Switch>
        { Object.values(Pages) }
    </Switch>
);
```

component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./history";




class Component extends React.Component {
    state = {
        username: undefined,
        password: undefined
    }

    onRedirect = () => {
history.push("/home");
}

    render() {
        const {token} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="auth">
                <a onClick={this.onRedirect}>Redirect</a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function mstp(state) {
    return {
        ...
    }
};

function mdtp(dispatch) {
    return {
        ...
        }
    }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mstp, mdtp)(Component));
export default withRouter(connect(mstp, mdtp)(Component));
```

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Comment: What is `history` version in package.json file?

Comment: "history": "^5.0.0"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react app showing empty page when redirecting on production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983627/react-app-showing-empty-page-when-redirecting-on-production-build)

Comment: Downgrade it to V4 as suggested in the linked post's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538).