# Set up router with history in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, router, history

I have 3 component and i want to make 2 button HOME and ABOUT (after click will redirect to page corresponding HOME (path '/') or ABOUT (path '/about'). Component NOTFOUND only show when path is wrong. But when i try to click HOME or ABOUT it always show NOTFOUND though the url has changed to '/' or '/about'. The details code is below, what must i do to make it work correctly. TKS all

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

function Home(props) {
    return (
        <div>Home</div>
    )
}

function AboutUs(props) {
    return (
        <div>About US</div>
    );
}
function NotFound(props) {
    return (
        <div>NotFound</div>
    );
}

function RouterDom(props) {
    
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
    
  
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/')}>Home</button>
                <button onClick={() => history.push('/about')}>About</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Count: {count}</div>
                <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Add</button>
            </div>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/about" component={AboutUs} />
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RouterDom;
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using version 4 of history package. See [react app showing empty page when redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538).

Comment: Thank you very much, i have changed version of history package and it work right now

Answer (score 0):

You should use Link provided from react router dom instead of buttons.

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

You should also add path property to the Route tag:

```
<Route path="/about">
   <About />
</Route>
```

Comment: Anyone ***should*** be allowed to use buttons, or any other component they see fit, and issue imperative navigation calls via the `history` object. Not every solution requires declarative navigation.